# Android : Google places are not showing

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, google-places-api

I am creating this app in which I want to fetch google places as soon as user type location in edittext.
I am using this library [Places Auto Complete Textview](https://github.com/seatgeek/android-PlacesAutocompleteTextView) , but I am not getting any suggestion for places, I have generated android key for places API, but I am getting no result.

Also Log doesn't show anything, Please check this github repo and tell me is there anything missing there or i am not getting something...

I am getting this error now

`An exception occured during performFiltering()!                                                       java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not yet implemented, please have Gson on your classpath`

Comment: Did you have the `gson` dependency in your classpath?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, can you help me in that?

Comment: are you using gradle?

Comment: yes I am using gradle

Comment: put this line in your build.gradle file (inside app folder), inside the `dependencies` tag:  `compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1"
`. Save, rebuild and run again

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan but now I am getting some kind of error

Comment: This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 150.129.238.71, with empty referer

Comment: ok. Now it is another problem (and another question). I will post an answer and please mark as correct, ok?

Comment: Yes it is very helpful, also I need to implement server key not android key, sloved issue, thanx mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project doesn't have the gson library configured correctly, and the `AutoCompleteTextView` that you are using need the gson inside your classpath.

Add this dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
     compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using uses the [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/), so you need to enable that API in the Google Developers Console, rather than  (or in addition to) the Google Places API for Android.